# How can I script a download from Windows File Sharing?

Tags: bash, server-message-block, redhat, cifs

Given a set of XML files available on a Windows Share \\server\share contains spaces\direcory\, I need a bash command to download one specific file from that share.

Neither wget nor curl support any smb:// URI, and I'd like to avoid the mount command. Solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

smbclient can be scripted to upload or download files using the -c option.  Syntax is similar to ftp.

e.g.

smbclient -I [server IP] "//servername/path with spaces/" -c "get [filename]"